# Grails/MongoDB delete all

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I have a Grails app with Mongodb in backend. I am trying to delete all the records of a collection as soon as a function is executed. This is what I tried in my ResourceController:

```
def report()
{
    Resource.where { }.deleteAll() //expected to delete all records from resource collection.
}
```

It doesn't work.

```
def report()
{
    def p = Resource.findAll()
    p.delete()
}
```

Neither approached worked. 
Is there any way to delete all records from a collection as soon as a method is executed? I read the documentation and it says that GORM doesn't support delete all. If anyone knows any workaround please let me know.

Comment: def p = Resource.list() then p*.delete() might work.

Comment: if it doesn't support delete then the only way to delete would be to call to the underlying driver directly.  Where did you find that it doesn't support deletes? - it's called remove in MongoDB and this page shows an example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-gorm-mongodb/

Comment: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/GORM.html states :  Grails does not supply a deleteAll method as deleting data is discouraged and can often be avoided through boolean flags/logic.

I will try this approach thanks

Comment: @JoshuaMoore sorry it didn't delete :( Asya's solution did work. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to remove all with the following syntax:

```
Resource.collection.remove(new BasicDBObject());
```

assuming Resource is a collection.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many different alternatives with no luck but the following line worked for me:

```
db.MEventCampaign.remove(version: 0) //or whatever means "all" for your data
```

For new domain definitions i switched to use flags for *new*, *updated*, *deleted*. Its working like a charm this way - but the collections are growing of cause.